# Python discord bot leave voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I've made bot to join my voice server like below

```
 if message.content.startswith("?join"):
    channel = message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    await message.channel.send('bot joined')
```

but i can't make bot to leave the channel.. how can i code to do it??
and what is the difference between

```
@bot.event
 async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('~'):
```

and

```
@bot.command()
async def ~(ctx):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do both of these commands (the join and leave channel commands) in two ways, one is by using on_message, and the other is by using @bot.commands. It's is best to use bot.command instead of on_message for commands as bot.commands has more features plus I think it's fast after all it was built for commands. So I'll rewrite both of your commands using bot.command and also put using on_message there incase you don't want to use bot.command. 
According to your message, I'm assuming `?` is your prefix

### Using `on_message`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.content.startswith('?join')):
        if (message.author.voice): # If the person is in a channel
            channel = message.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()
            await message.channel.send('Bot joined')
        else: #But is (s)he isn't in a voice channel
            await message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel first so I can join it.")

    elif message.content.startswith('?~'): # Saying ?~ will make bot leave channel
        if (message.guild.voice_client): # If the bot is in a voice channel 
            await message.guild.voice_client.disconnect() # Leave the channel
            await message.channel.send('Bot left')
        else: # But if it isn't
            await message.channel.send("I'm not in a voice channel, use the join command to make me join")
    await bot.process_commands(message) # Always put this at the bottom of on_message to make commands work properly
```

### Using `bot.command`

```py
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice): # If the person is in a channel
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send('Bot joined')
    else: #But is (s)he isn't in a voice channel
        await ctx.send("You must be in a voice channel first so I can join it.")

@bot.command(name = ["~"])
async def leave(ctx): # Note: ?leave won't work, only ?~ will work unless you change  `name = ["~"]` to `aliases = ["~"]` so both can work.
    if (ctx.voice_client): # If the bot is in a voice channel 
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect() # Leave the channel
        await ctx.send('Bot left')
    else: # But if it isn't
        await ctx.send("I'm not in a voice channel, use the join command to make me join")
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the channel connection, so you can disconnect later.

```
voice = None
...
    if message.content.startswith("?join"):
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        global voice = await channel.connect()
        await message.channel.send('bot joined')
    elif message.content.startswith("?join"):
        await self.voice.disconnect()
```

Anyways, try using the `discord.ext.commands` extension. It makes everything involving commands easier. I'd also recommend using cogs ([example](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be)), as you can just have a class with everything voice-related, and you don't need global variables.