# Im trying to make a simple discord bot that joins and leaves a voice channel, but I cant make the bot leave the channel

Tags: python, discord.py

```
# this command makes the bot join the voice channel
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await voice_channel.connect()

# this was my attempt to make it leave that does not work
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await voice_channel.disconnect()
```

The first command works and the bot joins the voice channel that I am in. But whenever I try to use the second command I get the error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'disconnect'

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You may wan't to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61164777/12203337).

Answer (score 0):

Leave the vc like so

```
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):  # If the bot is in a voice channel 
    await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Suggestion - check if bot is in vc or error might occur

```
if ctx.voice_client == True:pass
```